# the type specified in the typename property of objectdatasource could not be found when using a reference to a library

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a website and I use a Library for my Data connections,When I want to fill gridview , I use an objectdatasource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProject" runat="server" EnablePaging="true" TypeName="DMS.Data.ProjectProvider" SelectMethod="Search" SortParameterName="orderby" onselecting="odsProject_Selecting">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Code" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyID" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I Reference to my Library in website and config datasourceId of gridview but I get the below error:

> the type specified in the typename property of objectdatasource could not be found

what's wrong with my code? I search and see other posts but nothing help,

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is ok,I add reference,my method name and Namespace ,... is ok,

I only when Rebuild my Library again , My problem solved!